# Push message from Jenkins to PubNub

Tags: jenkins, push-notification, pubnub

What are some ways I can send a push from Jenkins upon build complete to PubNub? Is there any options to do a curl? Or do I have to write a javascript code e.g. in Node.js and attach that to execute on Jenkins after build is complete?

I will have a subscribed client listening written in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Push message to PubNub from Jenkins

To send status of Jenkins builds and deploys you can use `curl` or `wget` to post a JSON message using the PubNub HTTPS end-point.

[Publish PubNub Message with HTTPS](https://www.pubnub.com/http-rest-push-api/)

Here is an example `curl` you can use:

```
curl https://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/PUBKEY/SUBKEY/0/CHANNEL/0/{"json":"msg"}
```

[click here to test with your browser](https://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/demo/demo/0/hello_world/0/%7B"json":"msg"%7D)

It is really that simple!  Make sure to put in your Pub/Sub keys.  Also if you have PubNub Access Manager enabled you need to have a valid `Auth Key` appended to the url as a parameter.  Here is the format: `?auth=AUTHKEY`